# how to create an upload directive that isn't destroyed and cancels uploading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen so many angular upload directives, all of them have the same problem: since they are directives, they get destroyed once the user navigates to a different part of the webpage effectively cancelling anything the directive was doing with the files.

What is the correct way to work around this? should the directive only be glue and any uploading/file management be done in a service?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct way to work around this? should the directive only be glue and any uploading/file management be done in a service?

Yes. Once the user has picked a file, save the model using a service. If a user browses back and the upload field is shown again, show the picked file by populating it using the model stored in your service.